# How to p/Invoke CFDictionaryGetValue?

Tags: c#, macos, pinvoke

I'm trying to get a list of windows in my C# app on macOS. I have the following code:

```
public static class Native
{
    public static uint kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly = 1;
    public static uint kCGNullWindowID = 0;

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/BridgeSupport/CoreGraphics.dylib")]
    public static extern IntPtr CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(uint options, uint winid);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/BridgeSupport/CoreFoundation.dylib")]
    public static extern int CFArrayGetCount(IntPtr theArrayRef);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/BridgeSupport/CoreFoundation.dylib")]
    public static extern IntPtr CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(IntPtr theArrayRef, int index);

    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/BridgeSupport/CoreFoundation.dylib")]
    public static extern IntPtr CFDictionaryGetValue(IntPtr windowListRef, string key);
}

static void test()
{
    var windowList = Native.CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(Native.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, Native.kCGNullWindowID);
    int count = Native.CFArrayGetCount(windowList);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
    {
        IntPtr windowInfo = Native.CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowList, idx);
        var owner = Native.CFDictionaryGetValue(windowInfo, "kCGWindowOwnerName");
    }
}
```

I do get a windowList pointer back from CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo and I get a reasonable count from CFArrayGetCount. I get a pointer back from CFArrayGetValueAtIndex, but the program crashes when I call CFDictionaryGetValue.

A try/catch does not catch any error, the program just quits, and Visual Studio says, "The program '[30121] dotnet' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the C/C++ declarations of these functions?

Comment: const void *CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(CFArrayRef theArray, CFIndex idx);
const void *CFDictionaryGetValue(CFDictionaryRef theDict, const void *key);

Answer (score -1):

The type of `kCGWindowOwnerName` is [`CFStringRef`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/kcgwindowownername?language=objc), I don't think P/Invoke knows how to convert a string to CFStringRef, you have to manually do it by using one of the `CFStringCreateWith???` functions. For example:

```
var keyRef = Native.CFStringCreateWithCharacters(IntPtr.Zero,
    Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("kCGWindowOwnerName"), "kCGWindowOwnerName".Length);
```

BTW why not use [Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/)?

Comment: I have a fully functional app running on Windows and Mac (a Stream Deck plugin), and I only need to add this functionality. Learning and implementing Xaramin for this seems to be overkill and would just be to switch one unknown territory for another.

Comment: With these changes, I get an answer back, but it's always null.

 ```
[DllImport("CoreFoundation.dylib")]
        public static extern string CFDictionaryGetValue(IntPtr windowListRef, IntPtr key);

[DllImport("CoreFoundation.dylib")]
        public static extern IntPtr CFStringCreateWithCharacters(IntPtr nothing, char[] text, int chars);

 ```

Comment: The value of kCGWindowOwnerName is also a CFStringRef, you need to use CFStringGetLength and CFStringGetCharactersPtr to convert it to a C# string.

Comment: But I always get null back from CFDictionaryGetValue, so there isn't much I can do with it.

Comment: From your comment it's _"**string** CFDictionaryGetValue"_, it should be `IntPtr` as you wrote in the question. Have you tried `IntPtr`?

Comment: Yes, I tried IntPtr, and got IntPtr.Zero in return for all windows.

Comment: I found Xamarin uses `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni` to pass the string instead of `char[]`, I couldn't figure out the difference but it works for me.

Comment: Great, one step closer. :-) I now get a pointer back from CFDictionaryGetValue. Only the final step left - how to get the characters...